# Inheritance and polymorphism problems

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I have this code form the book SCJP:

```
1.  class Mammal {
2.    String name = "furry ";
3.    String makeNoise() { return "generic noise"; }
4.  }
5.  
6.  class Zebra extends Mammal {
7.    String name = "stripes ";
8.    String makeNoise() { return "bray"; }
9.  }
10.
11. public class ZooKeeper {
12.   public static void main(String[] args) {
13.     new ZooKeeper().go();
14.   }
15.   
16.   void go() {
17.     Mammal m = new Zebra();
18.     System.out.println(m.name + m.makeNoise());
19.   }
20. }
```

The result from running this code is "furry bray".

**Question 1**

I don't understand why line 17 is not :
    Zebra zebra2 = new Zebra();

What is the purpose in each of the following  cases, when to use which?

```
Mammal zebra1 = new Zebra();
```

vs

```
Zebra zebra2 = new Zebra();
```

**Question 2**

Why is the variable `name = "stripes"` from the `Zebra` class overridden by the `name = "furry"` from the `Mammal` class? I expect the opposote: the variable from subclass will override that from superclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer 1: Depends on what you want. In this case it is not that obvious. But sometimes you just want an object to be off class 1 or class 2. imagine you have a method in zebra and not in mammal and you want tot use that method, then your object needs to be off class zebra and not mammal. But if there is a third-party class with a method only accepting mammal variables, then you must pass a mammal object.

Answer2: m.name is the variable of mammal (cannot be overridden)  and m.makeNoise() is a method and this is overriden in Zebra.

Answer (score 6):

**Answer 1**

`Mammal zebra1 = new Zebra();` is used to show that you can assign objects of a derived class to variables of the parent class' type. That's also a reason for `Mammal m`, as you could also have a class `Lion` derived from Mammal and assign it to `m`. `m` can hold object of class `Mammal` or any class derived from `Mammal`.

**Answer 2**

This has also to do with inheritance. As you print out `m.name`, where `m` is a `Mammal`, you get the value of that property of the `Mammal` class. You cannot override variables by inheritance, only methods.
If you'd add a method `getName()` to both of your classes where both would return `name`, `m.getName()` would return `"stripes"`.

Comment: You're welcome. If you like my answer, please "accept" it (using the 'check' symbol at the left)

Answer (score 1):

1. Because `Zebra` **is** `Mammal`
2. Variables can't be overriden. If you change line 15 to:

   `System.out.println(((Zebra) m).name + m.makeNoise());`

   you'll get `stripes bray`